# Separator Color of one cell

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

how can i change the color of the separator line of my table view? But i want change only the first line.

This works for the whole tableview.

```
tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor blueColor];
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            tableView.separatorColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        } else {
            tableView.separatorColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Subclass UITableViewCell and put a line UIView at the top of the cell that can be accessed via a property (in storyboard or in code, whatever you like)
2. In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` set the color of the line view according to the row.

If you only want to change the first line, and by that you mean the top one as opposed to the line in between the first and second rows, then consider using UITableView's `tableHeaderView`.